# How to access the leading and trailing of the AVPlayerLayer when the videoGravity is set to resizeAspect?

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, avfoundation, avplayerlayer

I was wondering if it's possible to access the leading anchor and the trailing anchor of the `AVPlayerLayer` especially when the `videoGravity` property is set to `resizeAspect`. (I added an image and used red text to indicate where it is).

Currently, I'm working on a video camera app, and the view file, `LiveCameraView`, has one `UIView`, `videoView`, and the `videoView` is pinned to the `LiveCameraView`'s safe area (only the leading and trailing).
I want to set the [`videoGravity`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayerlayer/1388915-videogravity) as `.resizeAspect`, but I also want to pin the translucent black area's trailing (on the right side of the view which covers red and white record button) to the right-side edge of where the image is captured.

Sorry, it's hard to explain, but when I set the value to `.resizeAspectFill`, the whole width of the translucent black areas appeared. I want that happens when I use `resizeAspect` as well. So the right side of the `LiveCameraView` should display

- the full width of the translucent black area
- the black area since using resizeAspect
- Blue background area

So, I want to make sure somehow get the leading and the trailing of the `AVPlayerLayer` without the complete black area.
The `HKView` is a library I'm using and it's super class is `UIView`.

```
import AVFoundation

lazy var videoView: HKView = {
    let view = HKView()
    view.videoGravity = .resizeAspect
    return view
}()

lazy var rightContainerView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.translucentBlack()
    return view
}()

required override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupViews()
    setupConstraints()
    self.backgroundColor = .blue // put this for testing
}

func setupViews() {
    self.addSubview(videoView)
    hkView.addSubview(rightContainerView)
    rightContainerView.addSubview(recordButton)
}


func setupConstraints() {
    caneraView.anchor(top: self.topAnchor, leading: self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, bottom: self.bottomAnchor, trailing: self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor)
    
    rightContainerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        rightContainerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cameraView.topAnchor),
        rightContainerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cameraView.bottomAnchor),
        rightContainerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cameraView.trailingAnchor),
        rightContainerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cameraView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.15)
    ])
}
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah I had a similar problem recently. I got the size of the pixel buffer, then scaled it to the screen and calculated the difference

Comment: @aheze
Thank you for the response. Sorry to ask, but I'm too beginner to figure out what pixel buffer. 
Also, could you tell me what difference did you calculate and how did you do it?

Comment: "Pixel buffer" is pretty much the same thing as "image" - a sample image that you get from the camera feed. It might not be exactly what you are looking for, but here were my calculations: https://gist.github.com/aheze/931fc5cc32d1681c514b496f11fbf16a